# I want to update price before product added to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, event-observer

I am new in Magento, I am using Magento 1.9. I am making a module that will update price based on the width and height of the print, 
for that I create a module /app/code/local/Cart/Updates.
I created a file Cart_Updates.xml that I uploaded to a directory /app/etc/modules then module start showing on admin with code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <config>
     <modules>
       <Cart_Updates>
         <codePool>local</codePool>
         <active>true</active>
       </Cart_Updates>
    </modules>
  </config>
```

I created files config.xml and Observer.php

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <global>
    <models>
        <cart_updates>
             <class>Cart_Updates_Model</class>
        </cart_updates>
    </models>
    <events>
      <checkout_cart_update_items_after><!--Event to override price after adding product to cart-->
        <observers>
          <cart_updates_observer><!--Any unique identifier name -->
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>updates/observer</class><!--Our observer class name-->
            <method>updatePrice</method><!--Method to be called from our observer class-->
          </cart_updates_observer>
        </observers>
      </checkout_cart_update_items_after>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

I upload config.xml to /app/code/local/Cart/Updates/etc

and Observer.php to /app/code/local/Cart/Updates/Model

```
<?php
class Cart_Updates_Model_Observer 
    {

 public function updatePrice($observer){
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $product = $event->getProduct();
        $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
        $new_price = 30;
        $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);

        $quote_item->getQuote()->save();

    }   


      }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
class Cart_Updates_Model_Observer 
{

 public function updatePrice($observer)
 {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $product = $event->getProduct();
    $originalprice = $product->getPrice();
    $customprice = $originalprice + 20;
    $product->setPrice($customprice);

   }
 }
?>
```

**[Edit]**

[click here](http://mage-page.net/2012/08/create-the-checkout_cart_product_add_before-observer-in-magento/)

Or you can find your answer below link also. see answer of question

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574104/magento-checkout-cart-product-add-before-and-get-number-of-products-added)

May this help you.

Comment: i did it its also not working ,please please help me i am getting my hair out.My XML files are ok ?

Comment: Mage::log('dhirendra', null, 'dhirendra.log', true); not creating log file, mean problem is in calling observer  from xml file

Comment: You need to modify your module for that I edited my answer please see link and follow that steps. I think it's help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your observer code like this.

```
<?php
class Cart_Updates_Model_Observer 
    {

 public function updatePrice($observer)
 {
     $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();  
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $product = $event->getProduct();
        $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
        $new_price = 30;

        $quote_item->setCustomPrice($new_price);
        $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
        $quote_item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        $quote_item->getQuote()->save();

        $quote->save();

        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);

    }



      }
?>
```

Comment: i did but it is not updating the price on front end to 30 in cart please please help me

Comment: try to remove this line from code : $quote_item->getQuote()->save();

Answer (score 0):

Please use event **checkout_cart_product_add_after** instead of **checkout_cart_update_items_after**

**checkout_cart_product_add_after** is called immediately after product is added to cart.

**checkout_cart_update_items_after** is called when you update cart item from cart page, not when the product is added to cart.

Also you can not update price **before** product added to cart, You must update it **after** product added to cart **not before**.